# 3d plots in Matlab similar to Listplot3D in mathematica

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to plot a 3-D graph using matlab. I am unable to use the     "surf" command but when I plot it using the below command I am getting a line plot. I need something like a surface plot. Kindly suggest.

Here's my code

```
xx=[0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1., 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5];
yy=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
zz=[733.544, 630.535, 547.164, 479.489, 424.148, 378.498, 340.493, 308.56, 281.5, 258.383,238.468, 221.208, 206.13, 192.895, 181.194, 170.811, 761.517, 656.231, 570.406, 500.42, 442.994, 395.509, 355.894, 322.565, 294.288, 270.106, 249.262, 231.175, 215.385, 201.499, 189.235, 178.336, 789.005, 681.657, 593.518, 521.289, 461.821, 412.513, 371.31, 336.583, 307.085, 281.835, 260.063, 241.149, 224.624, 210.102, 197.26, 185.847, 815.984, 706.814, 616.488, 542.089, 480.609, 429.514, 386.728, 350.612, 319.893, 293.572, 270.857, 251.124, 233.869, 218.69, 205.269, 193.342, 842.45, 731.704, 639.313, 562.821, 499.384, 446.518, 402.147, 364.654, 332.711, 305.318, 281.659, 261.091, 243.1, 227.271, 213.27, 200.821, 868.394, 756.319, 662.007, 583.49, 518.139, 463.509, 417.582, 378.701, 345.54, 317.073, 292.469, 271.065, 252.332, 235.843, 221.252, 208.275, 893.798, 780.654, 684.553, 604.092, 536.854, 480.51, 433.031, 392.758, 358.38, 328.837, 303.285, 281.034, 261.553, 244.401, 229.218, 215.712, 918.66, 804.707, 706.953, 624.627, 555.551, 497.495, 448.47, 406.826, 371.229, 340.61, 314.094, 291.001, 270.773, 252.955, 237.174, 223.133, 942.963, 828.462, 729.205, 645.094, 574.228, 514.49, 463.925, 420.908, 384.09, 352.389, 324.91, 300.973, 279.982, 261.488, 245.109, 230.535, 966.693, 851.924, 751.311, 665.484, 592.874, 531.469, 479.394, 435.002, 396.96, 364.17, 335.735, 310.933, 289.187, 270.017, 253.028, 237.909, 989.834, 875.08, 773.252, 685.803, 611.488, 548.457, 494.864, 449.108,409.842,375.959,346.559,320.897,298.384,278.529,260.936,245.266];
scatter3(xx,yy,zz)
```

Comment: you may want to look into mayavi. It is better suited for 3d plots than matplotlib is (http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/). For matplotlib read: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: I went through the links you provided. Thank you :-) Mayavi seems to be a solution. However, can I not do this directly using something similar to  plot3 or scatter3 commands ? Is it needed to convert this to matrix and then draw the surface plot ?

Comment: wireframe is the matplotlib command you are looking for. Unfortunately, it is not as convenient as in matlab or mathematica.

Comment: But is it not similar to the mesh command ? I googled it and found this. Sorry about asking these many questions. I am confused

Comment: I do not really understand what you are looking for.  `Axes3D.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs)` is the command I now.

Comment: It was probably how to prepare my data for drawing a 3-d plot. Mayavi did this and it works great.. Thank you :-)

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I mistake matlab with matplotlib in your title. Sorry !

Comment: @Moritz Thats absolutely okay. This made me learn one more new thing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matlab [`surf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) and [`mesh`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) commands take **matrices** in input (and not vector).

Your `xx` and `yy` data already represent a grid but they are just not organised as such.

Simply [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your vectors in order to form a grid and you can use the Matlab functions:

```
X = reshape(xx,16,[]) ;
Y = reshape(yy,16,[]) ;
Z = reshape(zz,16,[]) ;

figure
subplot(1,2,1) ; surf(X,Y,Z)
subplot(1,2,2) ; mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

[image: surfandmesh]

Comment: This is great :-) Thank you :-) A small clarification here.. Why did you reshape the vectors to a size of '16' ?

Comment: Because if you look at your `xx` original data you will notice that they are repeated every 16 elements (and the `yy` have 11 groups of 16 identical elements). You could obtain the same grid by using `[X,Y] = meshgrid( 0.75:0.05:1.5 , 0:0.01:0.1 ) ;`. Look at the [`meshgrid`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) documentation to understand how Matlab prepare grid matrices for surface plots.